# ASP.NET Core passing an object to a view without passing it as a parameter in the action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create an edit form , when it autofills the properties of the object i use , but i want it to be an httpGet method so i have the httpPost method with the same name and there i'll submit the data to db. i can't use the same type object
What should i do?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditMessage(MessageModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }


    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditMessage(MessageModel newModel)
    {


        newModel.Update(_context);

        return View("Messages");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Okay so i found out how to resolve my problem.
ill just take the id of the object and pass that to the method.
in the method ill find what object has that id and pass that object to the view :)